# Keep getting "Bad request" with satellizer

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0, satellizer

I'm trying to login to the application using Facebook, but it always ends up with a bad request. I have read the documentation for Guzzle and Googled but no luck. Now i turn to you and hope that you can give me a hint.

This is the message that i got:

message:

```
"Client error response [url] https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?code=AQDRoV9AGzp-tltxQTh59UeYxfyGsThHQdc4UJ29fIh0g5iS1dKpmj2Bjjx-831WSUwVVYpIWD19crEFL0IrZPdHbl0g53bD4l1IvW0tbUTpSEzAZf-YO_zmHJFsYptwc-29DeuOuadHycPIA49O65SWQ9TDDJNSxXRmYtKYq2tbdwHczyxaupQA9IxIbaisHvHxaa3G6xURNKRiLSzKD9Qd_g4RHox-7vlYu4HZ2YljEnFAkmH7bYsKm61okTjv8JPhzQ16PXMcAwVOWpidMog7bGYzi09C7Prp5lkUUsvECIv1wwL2MNIXblDrdeW4GaU&client_id=1588368691378794&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9000&client_secret=445f1f93a81d0c24d5fbc4eb51ead669 [status code] 400 [reason phrase] Bad Request"

type: "GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException"
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Solved this one. It was a trailing "/" that was missing